# External Ubuntu hard drive does not show in Mac boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a MacBook Air (2016) that has MacOS installed on its internal SSD. However, for my work, I have Ubuntu 18.04 I recently installed onto an external hard drive. When I enter the Mac boot menu on startup (holding Option at startup), it gives me the options to boot from Macintosh HD or EFI Boot, but no option to boot from the Ubuntu hard drive. When I select the EFI Boot, it takes me to the GRUB loader where I can enter commands but cannot do anything else.

How can I configure my external hard drive such that it is recognized in the boot menu and can be booted from?

It is a 500 GB drive that is partitioned as follows: 200 MB EFI, 32 GB swap, 200 GB root, the rest is free space, if that matters.

Comment: What makes you think there is something special to configure? I'd be more worried about Apple's products ability to boot from USB.

Comment: I've also tried booting it on a Windows computer, and the device still did not appear in the boot menu